# Comparing excel data sets in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Pretty new to Python, but as an SEO I'm looking at the benefits of using notebooks in my workflow.

I've got two excel files which I've cleaned and imported into a new notebook using pandas.

I'm trying to compare position changes and create a new dataframe with new columns to show previous, new, and changes in positions.

Have a look at the screengrabs[! of the data below. Thanks in advance.

[image: Dataframe1]
[image: Dataframe2]

Comment: Could you briefly say what you want to do? like say you have dataframe 1 having columns {x, y, ...} and dataframe 2 with columns {z, m, n,...}. Now what are you planning to do with them? What would be the final dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `pandas.DataFrame.join` if you know how this works.

-- Edit: `merge` is apparently a better choice: See the example at the end.

I think you need an `outer` join on `Keyword`.

This should give a new DataFrame, that contains unique rows for the `Keyword` in both tables. Some entries may be NULL/None. This indicates that in the old or new table, the keyword was not present and you should treat is as a new keyword, or a keyword that has dropped from the list.

Rename the columns in the new table appropriately, and then apply a smart value between columns, taking into account that some values are NULL.

You can do a similar thing in Excel: https://superuser.com/questions/1023123/how-to-simulate-a-full-outer-join-in-excel

---

Edit:

Minimalistic example:

```
import pandas as pd

old = pd.DataFrame({'keyword': ['football', 'soccer', 'rugby'], 'position': [2, 1, 3]})
new = pd.DataFrame({'keyword': ['hockey', 'rugby', 'soccer'], 'position': [3, 2, 1]})

old.keyword = old.keyword.astype(str)
new.keyword = new.keyword.astype(str)

old.set_index(['keyword'])
new.set_index(['keyword'])

old = old.rename(columns={"position": "position_old"})
new = new.rename(columns={"position": "position_new"})

print(old)
print(new)

merged = pd.merge(old, new, how='outer', on='keyword')
print(merged)
```

Output:

```
    keyword  position_old
0  football             2
1    soccer             1
2     rugby             3
  keyword  position_new
0  hockey             3
1   rugby             2
2  soccer             1
    keyword  position_old  position_new
0  football           2.0           NaN
1    soccer           1.0           1.0
2     rugby           3.0           2.0
3    hockey           NaN           3.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, will give it try.

Comment: Regrettably still can't get it to work, but thanks for your input.

Comment: Thanks so much for the input, that makes sense, thanks for your help.